# Does a comprehensive list for apostolic succession exist?

Tags: catholicism, history, anglicanism, apostolic-succession

I'm actively studying apostolic succession and am trying to make a website (with API) that would try to make a timeline. However, finding the links between two bishops/priests is very hard to do.

I've tried using [Catholic Hierarchy](http://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/bishop/) but the results don't show whose consecrated who, and thus the link between them gets a bit iffy.

Of course, what I'm asking for might be something that I still don't yet understand entirely, but any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: A list of what?

Comment: @curiousdannii A list of bishops that include who consecrated them and who they consecrated.

Comment: Even if you limit it to only the Catholic Church that would be a huge undertaking. There are over 5000 Catholic bishops right now. The Catholic Church probably does keep records like that, but I don't know if they're consolidated, or if they're public.

Comment: As your question stands now it is too broad for this site. If you are looking for a list of active bishops and their consecrators, Rome does publish this list, but I can not recall the title of the book.

Comment: Ask your local Chancery Office, Benedictine Monastery or Catholic Seminary for help. They should be able to point you in the direction to go.

Comment: "_but the results don't show whose consecrated who_" Yes it does. See the page for [Abp. Lefebvre](http://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/bishop/blefebvre.html), to take an example. It lists his principal consecrator and co-consecrators. It also shows his "Episcopal Lineage / Apostolic Succession" back to the 16th century.

Comment: I see a difference between asking for a resource (which happens to be a list) and asking for a list. So I think this question is fine.

Comment: If this question is about present-day Catholic bishops only, it should be answerable. If it is about the putative bishops of Rome from the time of Peter and Paul, it is also answerable, although there are different and conflicting lists.  If it is, as currently stated, about apostolic succession in general, then it is far too broad.

Comment: @Nathaniel good point, vote-to-close retracted.

Comment: @Geremia Not all of the pages outline all of the consecrators unlike this one. Take [Bishop St. Conleth](http://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/bishop/bconleth.html) for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that [Catholic Hierarchy](http://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/bishop/) is currently the best tool for showing apostolic succession.

Keep in mind that written records only exist going back to the Renaissance, and they get spottier as we go back in history.

However, looking at (for example) the [page for Cardinal Timothy Dolan of New York](http://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/bishop/bdolan.html), scrolling down past the “events” table and “micro-data summary,” we see that Cardinal Dolan was ordained a bishop by then-Archbishop Justin Rigali. Clicking on (now) Cardinal Rigali’s link, we see that he was ordained a bishop by Pope St. John Paul II, and so forth.

There is another complication to keep in mind with regard to apostolic succession: most episcopal ordinations are acually *concelebrations*. That is, a minimum of *three* bishops lay their hands on the ordinand, and *all three* pronounce the essential words of consecration. The apostolic succession, therefore, could just as legitimately be traced through the so-called co-consecrators (visible just under the “principal consecrator” field). Moreover, there are often more than three concelebrants, and these do not make it into the records.

(The custom of having multiple consecrators—however it arose—has the advantage of removing, for all intents and purposes, all possible doubt as to the validity of the episcopal ordination.)

If you keep clicking, you will note that the vast majority of Western bishops can trace their lineage to a certain [Cardinal Scipione Rebiba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scipione_Rebiba). (This happened because [Pope Benedict XIII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Benedict_XIII), who traced his line to Cardinal Rebiba, consecrated no less than [139 bishops](http://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/bishop/borsini.html), for dioceses across Europe.) Unfortunately, we do not know who ordained Cardinal Rebiba a bishop (though there is no doubt that he was an auxiliary bishop in Chieti, Italy, and later archbishop of Pisa), so the written records largely stop there.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes, you can ask any apostolic church and you will get a list of bishops all the way to the apostles.
http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/12272b.htm

Comment: I don’t think any church has written records that go back any further than the Renaissance. What you can find is the list of bishops _in a given diocese_ (e.g., Rome, Milan, etc.) dating back to Apostolic or post-Apostolic times. But we have lost track of exactly ordained whom.

Answer (score -1):

Here is your answer from the Orthodox Church:
https://www.saintgeorgekearney.com/apostolic_succession

The Orthodox Church goes all the way back to the apostles and has never been broken.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Mark. We prefer longer answers. Perhaps you could elaborate on why your link is considered the correct answer.