# What is the base of the bible as the unique source of revelation?

Tags: bible, biblical-reliability

I'm interested in know from where come the fact that, in these times, the bible is the unique source of revelation, even when there are verses in the bible that explicitly says the oppose.

In John 16:12-13:

> 12 I have yet many things to say unto you, but ye cannot bear them now.
>
> 13 Howbeit when he, the Spirit of truth, is come, he will guide you into all truth: for he shall not speak of himself; but whatsoever he shall hear, that shall he speak: and he will shew you things to come.

What I understand is that Jesus says that there are things that need to be say and He doesn't say.

In 2 Joh 1:12:

> Having many things to write unto you, I would not write with paper and ink: but I trust to come unto you, and speak face to face, that our joy may be full.

Again, in this letter, John says that there are things that need to be said, but he prefers speak face to face.

I hope somebody may aclare my mind.

Comment: I think this has been asked before: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-is-the-basis-of-my-fractured-understanding-of-sola-scriptura

Comment: @MattGutting He is asking for: Where did the idea come from that everyone can interpret the bible for themselves? This is a different question

Comment: I believe it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Scripture is an aspect of Revelation, but not the whole of it by any means.

The Revelation is Jesus Christ, and Scripture is part of Revelation only because of its relationship to Christ.

Some Protestants might not agree with me on this, but Apostolic Christianity sees unwritten Tradition, prayers, and the Divine Mysteries/Sacraments, especially the Divine Liturgy/ Mass, as Revelation as well as Scripture.

Christi pax,

Lucretius

Answer (score 0):

Christians believe the Bible to be God's Word which is eternal and unchanging which is why we rely upon it as truth and revelation. Jesus is the Word made flesh - John 1:14. Which is also why Protestants rely upon scripture as our foundation for church traditions. Nothing within John 16:12-13 opposes that. Jesus is saying the Holy Spirit will come to reveal truth and guide them. In 2 John 1:12, the author is simply saying he is looking forward to visiting.

Comment: In 2 John 1:12, the author is not simply saying that, he also says that "Having many things to write unto you, I would not write with paper and ink"